# Add delimited text layer in QGIS 2.8

Tags: qgis

I have been successfully adding text delimited layers until today. Now the program freezes if I try this, and I have to press escape on my keyboard. Everything else works fine. I have just downloaded the new version (2.12.3), but have the same problem.

Does anyone know if there is a simple solution?

Comment: There is probably an issue with that file, what does head show you?

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry but I don't understand what you mean by 'what does head show you?'. I don't think this is a problem with an individual file, as the problem persists with any delimited text layer that I try to open, in any of the projects that I have been working on, or if I open a new project. I wonder if there is a check box some where that prevents the addition of delimited text layers? Any other comments or advice would be appreciated!

Comment: head is a common command line program that show us the first 10 lines of your file.

Comment: Thanks. I have installed an 'add spreadsheet layer' plugin, which has circumvented the problem.